# Number of threads per core in processors

Tags: multithreading, cpu-cores

is there is limitation for simultaneous executions of threads in a single core? Because, in the specifications of Intel processors, they mention say if a processor has 4 cores simultaneous execution of 8 threads is possible. Please clarify, kindly bear if it's totally abusrd

Comment: 4 cores with hyperthreading can run 8 threads simultaneously. If there are more threads, then time slicing is used to switch between threads of equal priority.

Comment: Read about simultaneous vs temporal threading: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading

Answer (score 1):

A 4-core processor can only run 4 threads simultaneously...

...technically...

...or at least that used to be true.

The pipeline of a [modern] CPU has several *stations* at which operations are stored. For example, when an instruction to fetch memory into a register comes along, it gets assigned to a station with all its dependencies and whatnot. A subsequent instruction to add 1 to that number is stored with a dependency on the fetch operation, which occupies that station until the fetch is completed.

As instructions are fed into the CPU, they get assigned to the stations. However, there are only so many memory-fetch stations, so if a fetch comes in but the fetch stations are occupied, it'll wait until that fetch is done.

This is what happens with one thread.

However, often times, two threads are doing different things: one might be doing a bunch of memory-fetch operations followed by integer-arithmetic operations followed by memory-store operations, whereas another thread might only want to do a bunch of floating-point-arithmetic operations... If only the first thread were allowed to execute, the floating-point-arithmetic operation stations would sit idle, unused.

So why not use them?

That's hyper-threading in a nutshell.

So, if you have threads doing the same operations, you effectively have four threads running at any given time.

If you have threads doing different things, you can increase your throughput to a theoretical maximum of eight threads running at any given time.

The more similar your threads, the closer to 4 you get; the more different your threads, the closer to 8 you get.